# Apply width to :first-line

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I would like to have a heading with the **first line shorter than the rest** of it.
Here is some [code](http://jsfiddle.net/qufo8db5/):

```css
div {
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
h3:first-line {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet who made up this fake Latin text</h3></div>
```

The first line is highlighted to demonstrate that background-color can be applied, but not the width, unfortunately.
**How can I apply a width to the :first-line pseudo element?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't specify the width of the `::first-line` pseudo element. For a list of properties you can apply to `::first-line`, see [MDN ::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line).

**Workaround:**

You can **make the first line shorter** with a right floated pseudo element :

```css
div {
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
h3:first-line {
  background-color: yellow;
}
h3:before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  width: 10em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet who made up this fake Latin text</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created this solution. I'm showing it on modified code from accepted answer. As you see no `:first-line selector` or `:before` pseudo element is needed. Percentage is for the gap on the right side. If you have used eg. `text-indent: 33.3%` it would make the first line wide 2/3 of the available space.

```css
div {
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height:1.2em;
}
h3 {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Nam quis eros eu urna commodo dignissim. Integer nulla justo, porta non rutrum nec, gravida non lectus. Integer sollicitudin, nunc sed egestas blandit, velit massa ultricies nisi, sed sagittis odio nisi ac tellus.</h3>
</div>
```

Not sure about its potential impact on accessibility however. But I don't think, that screen readers should care about text direction. Anyones opinion on this subject? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
div {
    width: 20em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
h3{
    background-color: yellow;
text-indent: 50px;
}
```

plz change your css with above css

Comment: This wouldn't be bad if I had completely right-aligned text as heading, but your solution pushes the first-line to the right, which is not the desired effect, sorry.